# How can I write a function that takes either one of many types in go?

Tags: go, types

I'm trying go for a small project and tried to write these functions:

```
func fatal(reason string) {
    println(reason)
    os.Exit(1)
}

func fatal(err error) {
    fatal(err.Error())
}
```

After digging about a bit and finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681871/golang-methods-with-same-name-and-arity-but-different-type), which referenced [the docs on overloading](https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading) I realised that what I was trying to do was illegal in go.

What I want is a simple api that allows me to call fatal with either a string or an error in order to simplify my logic. How do I achieve this or a similar goal?

It would feel inelegant to have `func fatal(reason string)` along with `func fatalErr(err error)`, is that what's needed? Am I missing a different feature of the language that allows me to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common way to do this would be to define the method as `func fatal(err interface{})` then do type assertions or use a type switch within it's body to handle each of the different types. If I were coding for your example it would look like this;

```
func fatal(err interface{}) {
     if v, ok := err.(string); ok {
         fmt.Println(v)
     }
     if v, ok := err.(error); ok {
          fmt.Println(v.Error())
     } else {
        // panic ?
     }
}
```

Also; here's a quick read about type switches and assertions that may be helpful; http://blog.denevell.org/golang-interface-type-assertions-switch.html
You can also check out effective-go as it has sections on both features.

Comment: Type switch and Type assertions. Thanks, that looks like exactly what I wanted to google. :). Seems a shame that we need to lose type information by casting it to an empty interface. Is there some way of creating a type that is either string or error and saying that our fatal function takes something of that type?

Comment: @MikeH-R you could declare an interface which both string and err implement. Your use case is a bit odd though. `error` is actually an interface and it's only method is `Error()` which returns the string you want to display as the error. Here's another idea... Make a single definition of `fatal` that accepts only `error` and then do `errors.New(theString)` when you have a string and pass the error into it. Here's the error packages source if you're curious; https://golang.org/src/errors/errors.go

Comment: Thanks evan, very helpful.

Comment: Because fmt.Println contains a superset of the logic in this answer, the function can be simplified to:  `func fatal(v interface{}) { fmt.Println(v); os.Exit(1); }`

Comment: @CodingPickle good update. As pointed out, `fmt.Println` checks if the type is an error and will print `input.Error()` if it is so there is actually no need to type assert or do anything if the two types you're dealing with are string and error. That being said, the question asks how to write a function which accepts multiple types so I supplied a generalized answer that explains how to handle these scenarios in Go, rather than just an example to demonstrate the lack of need in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Use log.Fatal() instead. https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatal

You can use interface{} but it is not recommended because you lose all the benefits of type checking when you do that. The Go authors get to use interface{} because they understand the appropriate level of additional testing and checks to do when using interface{}. It's much easier (even for intermediate and advanced gophers) to use builtin and standard library functions when something like this is required.

Go does not have algebraic or/sum types either. The standard workaround is to define an and/product type with pointers (e.g. struct{*string, *error}) and go to the effort of making sure you only ever make one of the fields non nil at any point in time.

Comment: Hi, thanks @voutasaurus. I was just moving from using `log.Fatal` to something else, It _almosts_ does exactly what I want, but I was getting annoyed by the timestamp that it prints so wrote (or tried to write) a helper function that was similar. (writing a small command line app and the timestamps feel unnecessary). Thanks for the tip and the info on OR types. (then again, you never can get a type system as nice as haskell elsewhere, sigh).

Comment: You can define your own logger that doesn't print the timestamp in one line: http://play.golang.org/p/TLMxtCag_0

Comment: hahaha, you're right! Serves me right for not reading up on the log package in the first place. Oh well, at least I learned something.

Comment: ... or you can change the flags on the default logger to suppress the timestamp:  `log.SetFlags(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Function overloading is not supported in the language. From the official Golang site it says,

> Method dispatch is simplified if it doesn't need to do type matching as well. Experience with other languages told us that having a variety of methods with the same name but different signatures was occasionally useful but that it could also be confusing and fragile in practice. Matching only by name and requiring consistency in the types was a major simplifying decision in Go's type system.
>
> Regarding operator overloading, it seems more a convenience than an absolute requirement. Again, things are simpler without it.

https://golang.org/doc/faq#overloading

One potential solution would be to define a high level function that type checks and handles different types similarly to how you would overload multiple functions. See @evanmcdonnal's solution for a great example.

Comment: I linked to that in my question. :)

Comment: You also didn't provide an answer of any sort, just a statement of fact. Try extending that idea to how you would handle this in Go rather than just stating you can't overload methods.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I was in the process of giving a high level explanation of exactly what you have an example of. Typing on a phone is not the most efficient way to answer. +1 to your answer.

Comment: Ah thank you. Sorry if that comment was rudely worded. Intended to be constructive.