# Exported functions from another package

Tags: go

I am following instructions in https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces link and I build my first Go program.

So, I tried to make library with this instruction = https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library

and everything is perfect until building hello.go, its gives me this error.

> /hello.go:10:13: undefined: stringutil.Reverse

I've already rebuild my `reverse.go.`

Thats my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/d35k/stringutil"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf(stringutil.Reverse("!oG ,olleH"))
}
```

that's my reverse.go (same as docs)

```
package stringutil

func reverse(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
    return string(r)
}
```

and my gopath variable

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/GoLang
```

and my files ar in

```
GoLang/src/github.com/mygithubusername/
```

Comment: use `go env` command in terminal and check for go root and go path variables.

Comment: GOPATH is correct, but goroot is in "/usr/local/go"

Comment: Please post your go path variable and your code for stringutil package

Comment: updated @Himanshu

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Golang Tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) specify exported name as

> A name is exported if it begins with a capital letter. And When
>   importing a package, you can refer only to its exported names. Any
>   "unexported" names are not accessible from outside the package.

Change the name of `reverse` func to `Reverse` to make it exportable to main package. Like below

```
package stringutil

func Reverse(s string) string {
    r := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(r)-1; i < len(r)/2; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i]
    }
    return string(r)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different problem with the same symptoms I ran into was that I was having two functions with the same name in Package B. Since two functions wih the same name but different types are no problem, I didn't think about it too much, however, VSCode didn't show the methods when I tried to use them in Package A, despite them being capitalized.

According to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681871)
this is not supported by Go and requires you to change the function name or use introspection/an interface.

Thought I'd share it since googling brought me to this question here multiple times and it might be something other Go learners might run into as well...