# Type Assertion using identical structs between packages

Tags: go, struct, interface, type-assertion

I am having a hard time understanding some type assertions in Go and why below code will not work and result in a panic.

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []db.job, not []main.job

Main:

```
/*stackTypeAssert.go
> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []db.job, not []main.job
*/

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "stackTypeAssert/db"
)

type job struct {
    ID     int
    Status string
}

type jobs interface{}

func main() {
    jobTable := db.GetJobs()
    fmt.Println(jobTable) // This works: [{1 pending} {2 pending}]

    //Type Assertion
    var temp []job
    //panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []db.job, not []main.job
    temp = jobTable.([]job)
    fmt.Println(temp)
}
```

Package db:

```
/*Package db ...
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []db.job, not []main.job
*/
package db

//GetJobs ...
func GetJobs() interface{} {
    //Job ...
    type job struct {
        ID     int
        Status string
    }
    task := &job{}
    var jobTable []job
    for i := 1; i < 3; i++ {
        *task = job{i, "pending"}
        jobTable = append(jobTable, *task)
    }
    return jobTable
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go lang spec for [Import declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations) it is described as:-

> The PackageName is used in qualified identifiers to access exported
>   identifiers of the package within the importing source file. It is
>   declared in the file block. If the PackageName is omitted, it defaults
>   to the identifier specified in the package clause of the imported
>   package. If an explicit period (.) appears instead of a name, all the
>   package's exported identifiers declared in that package's package
>   block will be declared in the importing source file's file block and
>   must be accessed without a qualifier.

As the error says:-

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []db.job, not []main.job

You should use the struct of `db` package by importing it inside main to create temp variable, since the returned value is an interface wrapping the struct `db.jobs` not `main.jobs`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "stackTypeAssert/db"
)

type job struct {
    ID     int
    Status string
}

type jobs interface{}

func main() {
    jobTable := db.GetJobs()
    fmt.Println(jobTable) // This works: [{1 pending} {2 pending}]

    // create a temp variable of []db.Job type
    var temp []db.Job
    // get the value of interface returned from `GetJobs` function in db package and then use type assertion to get the underlying slice of `db.Job` struct.
    temp = jobTable.(interface{}).([]db.Job)
    fmt.Println(temp)
}
```

In `db` package file define the struct outside `GetJobs()` function and make it exportable by converting the struct to `uppercase`.

```
package db
// make it exportable by converting the name of struct to uppercase
type Job struct {
    ID     int
    Status string
}

//GetJobs ...
func GetJobs() interface{} {
    task := &Job{}
    var jobTable []Job
    for i := 1; i < 3; i++ {
        *task = Job{i, "pending"}
        jobTable = append(jobTable, *task)
    }
    return jobTable
}
```

**Output**

```
[{1 pending} {2 pending}]
[{1 pending} {2 pending}]
```

For more information on exported identifier, you can check this link [Exported functions from another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50079815/undefined-stringutil-reverse/50080008#50080008)