# Method re-use in go code using controller-runtime

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubebuilder

I need help with method re-usage in Go.

I have two function signatures in my Kubernetes operator (in different controllers):

```golang
func myFunc(ctx context.Context, r *MyKindReconciler, myKind *myApiVersion.myKind) (ctrl.Result, error) {
```

and

```golang
func myFunc(ctx context.Context, r *MyOtherKindReconciler, myOtherKind *myApiVersion.myOtherKind) (ctrl.Result, error) {
```

The body of the function `myFunc` is the same in both cases, only the types of the variables that are passed in are different. Both `kinds` have the same methods available.

In order to prevent duplication, I’d like to move this method to a helper if possible. Any idea how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can use a generic function. Or, if you can abstract out the pieces of reconciler and ApiVerson.Kind to interfaces used in the function, you can define two interfaces for those and accept arguments of those interfaces.

Comment: "Both kinds have the same methods available." So make an interface and extract the common code into a function taking such an interface value.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am fairly new to go, might I ask you to provide an example?

Comment: Golang does not support method overloading:
May be given link will be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681871/golang-methods-with-same-name-and-arity-but-different-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work.

Here's the interace I build:

```golang
type MyObject interface {
    metav1.Object
    DeepCopyObject() runtime.Object
    GetObjectKind() schema.ObjectKind
}
```

A potential method signature looks like this:

```golang
func myFunc(ctx context.Context, client client.Client, object MyObject){}
```

Only downside `.DeepCopy()` will not be available as it returns a specific type and can't be overloaded in the `Interface`.